# css changes does not reflect in jade file

Tags: html, css

I am building this CRUD application in react and with redux. After setting up the node server and watch my css changes does not reflect in the main.css file. However the changes are there in the App.css file.
My index.jade file--

```
html
 head
   meta(charset='UTF-8')
   meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-
   height,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no")
   link(href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/
    css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
   link(hre='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
    awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet')
   link(href='#{domainName}/static/css/main.css', rel='stylesheet')
 title Menu Mapping
   script.
      window.domainName="#{domainName}"
 body()  
   #root
     script(src='#{domainName}/static/js/main.js')
```

---

Changes in App.css does not reflect in build>static>main.css even after I do npm run build. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a typo, `link(hre='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
    awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet')`

should be `link(href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
    awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet')`

(`hre` => `href`).

Other than that, did you check if `{domainName}` returned the correct value ?

By the way, this should not be tagged under `react/redux`, rather under `HTML/CSS`.

Comment: thanks for that. But whenever I make some changes in App.css it does not reflect anything in build>css>main.css

Comment: How is your `App.css` linked to your `main.css` ?

Comment: so the index.jade file runs whenever I do npm run start. And in that inde.jade file , I have imported main.css. But i do the changes in App.css. So they should be reflected in main.css but they do not

Comment: You did not answer my question. How does your code know that when you change `App.css`, `main.css` should update? Did you write it somewhere? Can you show me those files ?